# How to insert text in a file in a specific location?

Tags: python

I have a simple test.html with html content and I need a way to insert this text:

```
"bla bla bla..."
```

in this tag:

```
<p id="thislist"> </p>
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? There is tons of ways for doing what you want.

Comment: Nothing because I don't know if there is a way to do that. What is the simplest way ?

Comment: what about regex I think it suits here

Comment: @VigneshKalai: [Nope](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5299236)

Comment: @KevinGuan I never tried to read that. It confuses me in a lot of ways.

Comment: @VigneshKalai: Don't try to *read* that. Check the comments and that mod's note is enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try [`Beautifulsoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test.html') as f:
    html = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

tag = soup.find('p', {'id': "thislist"})
tag.insert(0, "bla bla bla...")
```

Comment: Removing previous comments every one needs coffee :p

Answer (score 0):

Match it using a regular expression and insert the content within it:

```
import re
some_string = 'puppies kittens <p id="thislist"> </p> ponies'
print re.sub(
    r'(<p id="thislist">)\s*(</p>)', r'\1bla bla bla...\2', some_string)
```

The output is

```
puppies kittens <p id="thislist">bla bla bla...</p> ponies
```

Comment: just tryed but doesn't work. it prints: puppies kittens <p id="thislist"> </p> ponies

Comment: What errors you seeing? That works on my python interpreter.

Comment: no error, just print: puppies kittens <p id="thislist"> </p> ponies instead of puppies kittens <p id="thislist">bla bla bla...</p> ponies

Comment: That's bizarre ... did you copy + paste into the interpreter? How are you running it? What version of python (find out with `python --version`)?